# Is there a term or a design pattern for an entity that traverses a tree

Tags: design-patterns

If you iterate over an array, you'd call that thing that iterates an Iterator.

What is the correct term for a thing going through an entire tree visiting every node and leaf? A traverser?

Is there a name design pattern for this?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge iterators are not limited to arrays. As you can see from c++ std library.

Answer (score 1):

There are several patterns that traverse trees and linked lists (such as Composite, Chain of Responsibility, Decorator, Interpreter etc).

There are different ways to traverse a tree - traversals - ie visit all nodes once in whatever order. They could all be reasonable be called iterators, but there is no special term.

Also its worth considering that an array looks suspiciously like a linked list, which is itself a special case of a tree.